# Eclipse Spring Boot - AutoConfigure cycle detected between TransactionAutoConfiguration and Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I had a really weird error starting yesterday on the Spring Boot application I am working on (1.5.2.RELEASE). I started getting the below exceptions when running the project in Eclipse.

When running it from the command line, everything worked fine (but I still need to run it from Eclipse when developing and debugging). I tried [deleting the .classpath file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9278), re-importing the projects, cleaning them in Eclipse, but the error persisted

```
2017-12-05 13:46:45.620 ERROR 11048 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@744ed1b7: startup date [Tue Dec 05 13:46:43 EET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]

<STACK-TRACE>

2017-12-05 13:46:45.635 ERROR 11048 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.almetis.webraadmin.WebRaAdminApplication];
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration  
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:545) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]

<STACK-TRACE>

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration   
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After upgrading my main project and libraries to use Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE, I could run my app in Eclipse again.

It seems there's a problem in the 1.5.2.RELEASE integration with Neo4J (see github [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9278) and [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8587)).

After taking a better look, I saw the reason: my main app was using Spring Boot 1.5.2 and one of the libraries it was consuming was using Spring Boot 1.5.8.

After playing around with the Spring Boot versions of my libraries and main app, I see:

- if all libraries and main app are using Spring Boot 1.5.2, all works well
- if all libraries and main app are using Spring Boot 1.5.8, all works well
- if a library is using Spring Boot 1.5.8 and the main app is using Spring Boot 1.5.2, then the exceptions in the question are thrown

The error is a little bit cryptic (to say at least), but the main take-away is to **keep all libraries and apps on the same Spring Boot version**.