# How to resolve "AutoConfigure cycle detected" during spring boot upgrade from 1.5.x to 2.1.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, upgrade

I'm upgrading spring boot of my project from 1.5.2 to 2.1.6 (The latest in the moment). After adjusting the code it finally builds successfully.

However, I can not start the application due to multiple "AutoConfigure cycle detected". Bellow are two of them :
1. AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration and
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration
2. AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration

I saw just a few not so popular questions on this topic on stackoverflow :
[Eclipse Spring Boot - AutoConfigure cycle detected between HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration and CacheAutoConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277626/eclipse-spring-boot-autoconfigure-cycle-detected-between-hibernatejpaautoconfi)

[Eclipse Spring Boot - AutoConfigure cycle detected between TransactionAutoConfiguration and Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653365/eclipse-spring-boot-autoconfigure-cycle-detected-between-transactionautoconfig)

**So, I wonder how in general "AutoConfigure cycle detected between" should be resolved?**

What I have tried is to add exclude in @SpringBootApplication annotation. This helps me temporary to workaround the issue but a bit later I'm in different troubles... I'm not sure if they are connected with this excludes or not.

For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, CacheAutoConfiguration.class})
public class InitApplication {
```

skips AutoConfigure cycle detected between org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration
error message.

Answer (score 2):

This is problem with Springboot  and spring-data-jpa version issue. I tried above solution but still giving entityManager and TransactionManager bean failed to created.

I have added few annotation on Application Driver class that perfectly working for me.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { CacheAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```